# Not able to call out Firewall VPC Endpoints via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm unable to create a route in my route table so points to the firewall VPC Endpoints. I'm currently using ~>3.0 AWS Provider.

```
    resource "aws_route_table" "internet_gateway_rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.this.id

  route {
    cidr_block      = var.cidr_block[0]
    vpc_endpoint_id = (aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status.0.sync_states.1.attachment.1.endpoint_id)[1]

  }
  route {
    cidr_block = var.cidr_block[1]
    vpc_endpoint_id = (aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status.0.sync_states.0.attachment.0.endpoint_id)[0]  
    }
  route {
    cidr_block = var.cidr_block[2]
    vpc_endpoint_id = (aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status.0.sync_states.2.attachment.2.endpoint_id)[2]
  }
```

Does anyone know how I can retrieve the IDs?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: I've managed to do this by doing the following:

Creating a local variable:   firewall-eu-west-2a = {
    for_each        = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall
    vpce_eu-west-2a = [for ss in aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status[0].sync_states : ss.attachment[0].endpoint_id if ss.availability_zone == "eu-west-2a"]
  } creating a for each loop to grab each endpoint_id based on the filter of the AZ